# Proving some inequalities related to Information Theory

Tags: inequality, information-theory

I've been working on some inequalities related to the information theory
section of my decision theory course, and I could use some help on some of
the derivations for one of the inequalities.

As a reminder,
$$H(P) = -\sum_{i=1}^n p_i \log(p_i)$$
$$H(P,Q) = -\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^m \mathbb{P}(P = i, Q = j)
\log(\mathbb{P}(P = i, Q = j)).$$
I want to prove that
$$\max\{H(P),H(Q)\} \leq H(P,Q) \leq H(P) + H(Q).$$
The lower bound is quite easy: given a particular lemma that states
$H(P,Q) = H(P|Q) + H(Q) = H(Q|P) + H(P).$ The upper bound is quite tricky,
since it comes down to proving
$$H(P,Q) \leq H(P) + H(Q)$$
$$\leftarrow H(P|Q) + H(Q) \leq H(P) + H(Q)$$
$$\leftarrow H(P|Q) \leq H(P)$$
$$\leftarrow 0 \leq H(P) - H(P|Q),$$
I.e. we need to show the information gain of $P$ given $Q$ is always
non-negative. Any suggestions on how to approach a problem like this?

Answer (score 2):

Essentially, Jensen's inequality.

\begin{align}
H(P) - H(P \mid Q)
&= - \sum_i p(i) \log p(i) + \sum_j p(j) \sum_i p(i \mid j) \log p(i \mid j)\\
&= - \sum_{i,j} p(i,j) \log p(i) + \sum_{i,j} p(i,j) \log p(i \mid j)\\
&= -\sum_{i,j} p(i,j) \log \frac{p(i)p(j)}{p(i,j)}\\
&\ge -\log \sum_{i,j} p(i,j) \frac{p(i)p(j)}{p(i,j)}\\
&= -\log 1\\
&= 0.
\end{align}